# Insert a picture using VBA, different size between Excel 2010 and Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2016, vba

I'm writing because I'm struggling in trying to understand why I get 2 different results when importing a picture using VBA.

The image source is:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=390x280&zoom=8&maptype=terrain&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C18.510516,-72.287768&key=mykey`

And I'm using this VBA code to insert the picture in cell `Z8`:

```
Range("Z8").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL).Select
With Selection
.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.999, msoTrue
End With
```

*the `.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.999` is not need in this specific case but even if I remove the `With Selection` instruction, I get the same output.

If I run the VBA code in Excel 2010, which I used to build the worksheet, everything is looking great, as shown below:

[image: Excel_2010]

but when I run the VBA code in Excel 2016, I get something different:

[image: Excel_2016]

The picture in this case is larger and off the page limits. The same is happening also for the QR code you can see on the top left. Also the vertical (and horizontal) page breaks have moved (and I cannot explain myself why) but I'll keep this question for another message.

In general the picture in Excel 2016 is 1.25 larger than the picture in Excel 2010. Excel 2016 is installed on another laptop with a **different screen resolution**. Could be this the reason for the issue I'm facing? If so, do you know a way to fix it in a way that is screen-resolution independent?

Thanks, Stefano

Comment: It may be wiser instead to simply make sure that the image you insert is of a certain size by resizing it after you insert it

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'll try to assign the picture size in pixel with `.ShapeRange.Width = xxx` and `.ShapeRange.Height = xxx`. My question is: is not the same thing I'm doing with `.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth`? My picture is (see the URL) 390x280 px, I don't understand why in Excel 2010 everything is fine with a scale factor of 1.00 while in Excel 2016 I need a scale factor of 0.80.

Comment: I tried the fix suggested by @rlb.usa but i got a very similar result: in Excel 2016 the picture is larger than the one in Excel 2010, even using `.ShapeRange.Height = xxx`. I also just realized that it might depend on the the screen resolution. I checked both laptops and the one with Excel 2010 is 1920x1080 (factor scale 113%) and the one with Excel 2016 is 1920x1080 (factor scale 125%) I will perform some additional test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft introduced new picture resolution and compression handling processes beginning with Excel 2010, and then tweaking the defaults as technology quickly improved over the next few years.  This could be responsible for your issue.

Your varying monitor sizes/resolution between your machines will also affect the default (and available) settings.

> Even though the monitors are different sizes, it would be helpful to try to set your Windows *Display Resolution* to the same value on both, at least temporarily.
>
> The steps vary slightly depending on which version of Windows you're running, but they're not hard to Google.  (For example, **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/14108/windows-7-change-screen-resolution)** are instructions for Windows 7 installations.)

Check the following settings on *both* computers to ***see which options are available*** (not greyed-out) **before** changing anything, because you'll need to decide on a setting that is available on both.

---

### Default Resolution Settings

- In Excel, click `File` → `Options`
- On the left side of the dialog, choose `Advanced`
- On the right side of the dialog, scroll down to `Image Size & Quality`
- Take note of which settings are **selected** and which are **available**:

  `☑ Do not compress images in file` (checkbox)

  `Default Resolution` (drop-down)

[image: options 1]

For the next step you'll need to have a picture on a worksheet, so you may as well use the "problem images" from your example.

- Single-click the image to select it. This should make the `Picture Tools / Format` menu appear.
- Click `Compress Pictures`
- In the dialog that opens, under `Resolution`, take note of which settings are **selected** and which are **available.**

[image: options 2]

Hopefully there's a combination that is available on both machines.  Once you've set them both the same, reboot both machines, and try inserting the pictures again.

As I mentioned, there could be a number of factors affecting it. The only way to ensure graphics behave identically on two separate machines is if they have identical software *and* graphics hardware.

---

If all else fails and you want to try one more long-shot, there is a **Registry Setting** that may be affecting one or both machines.

It's tough to find documentation on Office's thousands of registry settings (many not used by default, such as this one) - and one **[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2713852/image-resolution-and-size-change-from-a-webpage-in-excel-2007-2010)** implies that this only affects resolution of images in Office documents that are converted to web pages.

However, I believe that if you've *ever* saved an Excel document as a web page, this registry key (and it's related "known issue") could have been affected as well, so you could double-check.

---

### Registry "Hack"

To work around this problem, add the following registry key to prevent the size change of the image.

> ***Standard Registry Warning:***  Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using
>   another method. These problems might require that you reinstall your
>   operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can
>   be solved. **Modify the registry at your own risk.**
>
> 1. Exit all programs.
> 2. Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> Windows Key, type `regedit`, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 3. Locate and then select the following registry subkey:
>
>    **`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common`**
> 4. After you select the subkey, click the `Edit` menu, click `New` and choose `DWORD Value`.
> 5. Type `DownRevRasterizationDPI`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 6. Right-click `DownRevRasterizationDPI`, and then click `Modify`.
> 7. In the **`Value`** data box, type a value in the range of `1` to `300` and then click `OK`.
>
> > In the **`Value`** data box, set a value of the resolution that you want to specify for the image. For example, if you set `96`, which is a
> >     default screen resolution value for Windows, and insert a screenshot
> >     into Excel, the image resolution of the screenshot becomes `96 dpi`.
>
> 8. On the `File` menu, click `Exit` to exit Registry Editor.

Normally I like to include links to "More Information" in my answers, but I'm afraid *there just isn't much out there* besides the source link (above).

Good luck!